# boost asio doesn't recognize timer object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to run boost example from the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2/src.html) timer2

this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_context io;

  boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(5));
  t.async_wait(&print);

  io.run();

  return 0;
}
```

and I'm getting the following errors: error: ‘io_context’ is not a

> member of ‘boost::asio’    boost::asio::io_context io;
> ^~~~~~~~~~ /home/mosh/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:62:16: note: suggested
> alternative: ‘connect’    boost::asio::io_context io;
> ^~~~~~~~~~
> connect /home/mosh/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:64:16: error: ‘steady_timer’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio’
> boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(5));
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~ /home/mosh/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:64:16: note: suggested
> alternative: ‘deadline_timer’    boost::asio::steady_timer t(io,
> boost::asio::chrono::seconds(5));
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> deadline_timer /home/mosh/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:65:3: error: ‘t’ was not
> declared in this scope    t.async_wait(&print);    ^
> /home/mosh/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:65:3: note: suggested
> alternative: ‘tm’    t.async_wait(&print);    ^    tm
> /home/mosh/Desktop/untitled1/main.cpp:67:3: error: ‘io’ was not
> declared in this scope    io.run();    ^~

Comment: what is you boost version?

Comment: my boost version is 1_58

Comment: you are using example of 1.73 try this [one](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2/src.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have boost version 1.58 you need to change your code according to the [relevant version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2/src.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp> // <- look at this header

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5)); //<- this deffernt 
  t.async_wait(&print);

  io.run();

  return 0;
}
```

also, don't forget to link in your make/CMake file to boost_system